# Retrieving Information from Specific UICell Using Swift

Tags: swift

In my program, I have an UITableView and I need to access a label in one of the UITableViewCells. I have the indexPath for the UITableViewCell, but I was wondering how I should proceed in grabbing the cell's label using Swift. Any ideas on how you access a cell without being in the table view swift file?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't go through the cell to grab the content of the label. Instead, you should go through whatever data structures that you used to set that label in the first place.

Go to your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` code, and find the part where you set up the label in the cell

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row] // <<== HERE
    return cell
}
```

You have code similar to the above, where you use the source of data to set up your label from an `indexPath`. Using the same code to obtain the text that went into your label provides the most direct way of getting the data.